# RxJava BehaviorSubject not emitting last item?

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a simple RxJava, using ReplaySubject, I could get the result, where all 3 numbers are printed.

```
    val observable : Observable<Int> = Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
    val subject = ReplaySubject.create<Int>()
    observable.subscribe(subject)
    subject.subscribe{
        result ->
        System.out.println("Start $result in Subscription Result")
    }
```

When I change to Behavior, I expect the third number i.e. 3 to be printed, as I always thought Behavior is to replay the last emitted item.

```
    val observable : Observable<Int> = Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
    val subject = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>()
    observable.subscribe(subject)
    subject.subscribe{
        result ->
        System.out.println("Start $result in Subscription Result")
    }
```

However it doesn't print anything. Why?

Did I miss anything important here? If yes, let me know how to get the supposing emitted last item (i.e. 3) printed.

Comment: `BehaviorSubject` doesn't retain the last item after completion by design. You should use `ReplaySubject.createWithSize(1)` to have the altest always replayed, even beyond the upstream completing.

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd. How if I just want the last item to be emitted, but not all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not print anything because subsription has already terminated. If the subscription is still active then 3 will be printed, for example:

```
val o1: Observable<Int> = Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
val o2: Observable<Int> = Observable.just(4).delay(100,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
val observable: Observable<Int> = Observable.concat(o1, o2)
val subject = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>()
observable.subscribe(subject)
subject.subscribe{
    result ->
    System.out.println("Start $result in Subscription Result")
}
Thread.sleep(1000)
```

Both 3 and 4 (after delay) will be printed, with 3 emitted as most recent event before the subscription and 4 is emitted after the subscription.

Additionally as explained by @akarnokd in the comment section `ReplaySubject.createWithSize(1)` can be used to always replay last item even after observable completion and if single item is needed regardless of stream completion state then `observable.takeLast(1).subscribe(subject)` can be used to guarantee that:

```
val observable : Observable<Int> = Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
val subject = ReplaySubject.createWithSize<Int>(1)
observable.takeLast(1).subscribe(subject) //can be moved after subject.subscribe as well
subject.subscribe{
    result ->
    System.out.println("Start $result in Subscription Result")
}
```

Comment: Yes, that explains why it no longer have the last item, because it is completed. But if I want to have the last item emitted still, is there a way?

Comment: As @akarnokd explained you can use `ReplaySubject.createWithSize(1)` to always replay last item.

Comment: It works fine, just 3 is replayed. Can you paste your code?  Are you sure observable has terminated at time of subscription? the javadoc states the guarantee explicitly:
"When observers subscribe to a terminated `ReplaySubject`, they are guaranteed to see at most `size` `onNext` events followed by a termination event."

Comment: I basically replace `val subject = ReplaySubject.create<Int>()` with `val subject = ReplaySubject.createWithSize<Int>(1)`, per my first sample code above.

Comment: Not sure what is happenning, which version of rx are you using? Anyway, you can guarantee single event but modifying the observable with `observable.takeLast(1).subscribe(subject)`, this will work regardless of the subscription state.